# block access from subdomains in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to allow access to socket.io only if the website the connection is coming from is one of the whitelisted subdomains on my server. The best would be if I could check the origin subdomain everytime a client connects to my socket.io server. I tried finding out how to do it, but haven't found a good solution yet.
The only thing that comes close to a solution is [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843199/2857873). However - I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it and if that even works in my case and can't be faked via javascript.

**TLDR**: How do I treat socket.io requests differently based on their origin? If that's not possible: How do I host two socket.io servers on two subdomains, but same port?

**Regarding duplicate flag**: My Question is entirely different. I cannot use namespaces as a solution since I can't trust the client side javascript running on some subdomains. Therefore these subdomains could just join a different namespace, which would make my efforts to separate them pointless.

Comment: [Possibly relevant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674884/socket-io-on-subdomains-with-express-js-vhost)

Comment: aug unfortunately that kinda only does the opposite. I want to keep most of my subdomains out of my socket.io server, not include them. I can't trust some of the client side javascript on some subdomains and therefore can't use namespaces, as the client side js can easily join another one.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer with the help of some guy on the socket.io slack server.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var subdomain = socket.handshake.headers.host.split('.')[0];
    if (subdomain === 'allowed') {
        socket.on('login', /* ... */);
    } else {
        socket.on('login', function () {
           console.log('login disabled, wrong subdomain'); 
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know it it's reliable or can be modified by malicious client javascript, but it was looking quite good while I was testing it.

Comment: Just realize that http headers like this can be spoofed by any programmable agent connecting to your server.  This will probably work for connections coming from a standard browser because they don't spoof or allow Javascript to spoof.

Comment: Yeah, I think there is no way to block that, but I only use this code to secure users using my application from javascript files gaining more api access than they allow. But if the user wants to hack his own account by setting up a custom browser/agent - that's none of my business. :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the this modifie code to the express/socket.io middleware function so it gets called on every request: connect, disconnect, and streaming.

I also use the express-subdomain npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain

```
   app.sio.use((socket, next) => {
      var subdomain = socket.request.headers.host
      sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next)
   })
```